# Xamarin.UWP Custom ViewCell has problems with the bindings

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I've created a custom ViewCell that's supposed to be used in my ListView
Same code works on Android but not on UWP (Windows Phone and Windows desktop alike).

The project is Xamarin Forms.

[image: Differences]

When I use it within my ListView...I can only see blank cells.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AAA.Extensions.AttributeViewCell"
            Tapped="AttributeViewCell_OnTapped"
          >
<Grid
    x:Name="AttributeGrid"
    >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackLayout
        Grid.Column="0"
        >
        <Label
            Text="{Binding Code}"
            TextColor="#000000"
            />
        <Label
            Text="{Binding Description}"
            TextColor="#000000"
            />
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout
        Grid.Column="1"
        x:Name="DynamicContentStackLayout"
        >

    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

**My code behind**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class AttributeViewCell : ViewCell
    {
        #region Bindable Properties
        public static readonly BindableProperty CodeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Code),typeof(string),typeof(AttributeViewCell), defaultBindingMode:BindingMode.TwoWay);
        public static readonly BindableProperty DescriptionProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Description), typeof(string), typeof(AttributeViewCell), defaultBindingMode:BindingMode.TwoWay);
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// Attribute Code
        /// </summary>
        public string Code
        {
            get => (string) GetValue(CodeProperty);
            set => SetValue(CodeProperty,value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Attribute's description
        /// </summary>
        public string Description
        {
            get => (string) GetValue(DescriptionProperty);
            set => SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value);
        }
        #endregion

        public AttributeViewCell()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            this.BindingContext = this;
        }

        private void AttributeViewCell_OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // I CAN SEE BINDINGS here...
        }
    }
```

The binding is being done throughout a ViewModel
The POCO's look like the following

```
public class Attribute
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

VM
    public class ProductDetailsPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
        {
            #region Fields
            private readonly AnonymousCheckerService _anonymousCheckerService;
            private List _attributes;

```
        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public List<Attribute> Attributes
        {
            get => _attributes;
            set
            {
                _attributes = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        //basic ctor
        public ProductDetailsPageViewModel()
        {
            _aaa= new aaa();
            Attributes = _aaa.GetInfo("123").Attributes;
        }
    }
```

And finally, the ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:extensions="clr-namespace:AnonymousCheckerApp.Extensions"
             x:Class="AnonymousCheckerApp.Views.ProductDetailsPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding Attributes}"
            >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <extensions:AttributeViewCell
                        Code="{Binding Code}"
                        Description="{Binding Description}"
                        AttributeDetails="{Binding AttributeDetails}"
                        />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

and it's codebehind
public ProductDetailsPage()
        {

            var vm = new ProductDetailsPageViewModel();
            this.BindingContext = vm;

            InitializeComponent ();
        }
```

I've attached a Tapped event on the viewcell...I can see the bindings...

[image]

**Edit 1**

I've commented out the Grid code as I've found some other devs having issues with binding on elements stacked within `Grid` elements...
Still not working and what's weird is that it properly "parses" the XAML elements but it fails to do the binding....What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

This is how it looks on Android
[image]

Comment: Isn't it a different problem, maybe the text is white for some reason? Could you set the `TextColor` to Red or anything just to rule it out :)

Comment: I've updated the main thread...still not working, if I replace the Text={Binding} with some harcoded value it'll render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and reproduced your issue. This line `this.BindingContext = this;` is unnecessary. Because the `AttributeViewCell` is inherit ViewCell and you can use it in ListView `DataTemplate` directly. So Please delete the following line code from `AttributeViewCell` constructor.

```
 this.BindingContext = this;
```

[image]